# Getting stylegan to run on gcp instance with v100

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab, google-dl-platform

I have been trying to get stylegan to run on gcp to connect to a v100. I have been able to do training for 1d using this instance setup

```
 export IMAGE_FAMILY="pytorch-latest-gpu" # or "pytorch-latest-cpu" for non-GPU instances
export ZONE="us-west2-b" # budget: "us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-fastai-instance"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-highmem-8" # budget: "n1-highmem-4"

# budget: 'type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1'
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"
```

for a large dataset, then I run the same code for another dataset and it seems to not be using the v100. I had to run !pip install tensorflow-gpu both times

when I try the code on with

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="tf-latest-gpu" # or "pytorch-latest-cpu" for non-GPU instances
export ZONE="us-west1-a" # budget: "us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-fastai-instance"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-highmem-8" # budget: "n1-highmem-4"

# budget: 'type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1'
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"
```

I get errors when running the data_tool.py file to create records and cant run python3 for some reason in a jupyter lab environment.

Also all of the code is working on google colab which makes we wonder what type of instance colab has and if I can just find the script to setup the same instance with a v100?

Answer (score 1):

Your first command:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="pytorch-latest-gpu" # or "pytorch-latest-cpu" for non-GPU instances
export ZONE="us-west2-b" # budget: "us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-fastai-instance"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-highmem-8" # budget: "n1-highmem-4"

# budget: 'type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1'
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"
```

uses image family `pytorch-latest-gpu` this image does NOT have TensorFlow pre-installed and should not be used with TensorFlow tasks.

as for the second command it is using `tf-latest-gpu` family which is the correct one. May I ask to provide more details for us to help:

- what are the code that you trying to run?
- can you copy-paste error here?
- if it is working on a Colab maybe you have link to the public Colab notebook?

BTW, Colab is using 1 K80 GPU.